# Invalid Apple Watch icon file names must match pattern "*<dimension>@<scale>x.png"

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit, apple-watch

I'm trying to submit an update to my App to include Apple Watch capabilities, however whenever I validate the build I get the errors detailed in the screenshot below. Looking at the bottom error my file name seems to be matching the pattern so I don't see what the issue is. If I can get the pattern right for 1 icon then I can apply the same logic across the board, however I'm not having much luck with it.

Has anyone else had this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I got the same issue when I tried to submit.  My problem was that I was sharing my image asset file with both my iOS app target and my WatchKit app target.  You need to have a separate image asset file for your WatchKit app and it should ONLY have images for the Apple Watch in it.  That fixed it for me.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any documentation on this? I was searching for a while but found nothing by Apple that discusses this in detail.

Comment: It's not documented because I believe it's a bug. We have already told apple about this.

Comment: I did not find any documentation on this, this is just what worked for me.

Comment: In my WatchKit App's images.xcassets file I named "AppIcon" to "AppIcon-Watch" and linked it up in the project's settings (target = WatchKit app)

Comment: Xcode 9 also doesn't set up watchOS 1 app icons correctly, it seems. Give the asset catalog everything it wants and you still get a submission error.

Answer (score 32):

For me, the issue was that I still shipped the watchOS 1 Long Look icon (44X44@2x) even tho I no longer supported watchOS 1. Once I unchecked the bod for watchOS 1.0 in the assets and deleted the no longer needed icon, I had no problems.
[image]

Comment: I added that icon a while back because it wouldn't submit without, now I had to delete it again. Thanks Apple, for not making our lives too easy! =)

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem, none of the sollutions above worked for me.

Instead of submitting the app, I exported an IPA, and had a look of its contents. Turned out there was duplicates of my icons in there, but named differently.

I renamed my files according to the files I found,  drag and dropped them to their places in AppIcon, archived, submitted and IT WORKED!

**Proper naming of the WatchKit icons:**
AppIcon24x24@2x.png
AppIcon27.5x27.5@2x.png
AppIcon29x29@2x.png
AppIcon29x29@3x.png
AppIcon40x40@2x.png
AppIcon44x44@2x.png
AppIcon86x86@2x.png
AppIcon98x98@2x.png

Comment: renaming my watch icons to the above was one of the steps that helped me through this arduous process

Answer (score 1):

I just used [this template](http://appicontemplate.com/watch) and everything went smoothly, just make sure your images don't have alpha channels.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. This is how I fixed it:

1) changed my name format to: Icon_24@2x.png

2) Removed files from derived data (I used Watch Dog for XCode for this - https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/watchdog-for-xcode/id734258109?mt=12)

3) Closed and re-opened Xcode

Then my archive validation succeeded. I think the derived data removal was the actual fix, but I changed my icon name format at the same time so cannot be sure if the name change also contributed.

I hope this helps.

Comment: deleting the derived data was one of the steps that helped me through this arduous process

Answer (score 1):

Okay I finally figured it out myself: Here is what I did, and along with about 30 attempts to submit it, I finally don't have issues with this. Only the last thing I did for 100% made the difference, but I thought I would share because this problem was about a 6 hour issue (along with other junk I had to fix that normally I wouldn't for a normal universal iOS app)

1) Deleted all my derived data by going to Library/Developer/Xcode/ or something like that.

2) Clean, Clean Folder

3) Rename all icons for Watch to these names:

```
AppIcon24x24@2x.png
AppIcon27.5x27.5@2x.png
AppIcon29x29@2x.png
AppIcon29x29@3x.png
AppIcon40x40@2x.png
AppIcon44x44@2x.png
AppIcon86x86@2x.png
AppIcon98x98@2x.png
```

4) Use one Images.xcassets file. This file has 3 main objects in it: 
   a) Icons for iPhone and iPad
   b) Icons for Watch
   c) Splash Screen Images for iPhone and iPad

5) Clean up the Images.xcassets by tapping show/hide Utilities on the top right of the window in Xcode. (only have icons for iPhone and iPad in the first object, only have Watch Kit icons in the second object). Also, remove CarPlay icons

5.5) Also goto the regular app's target, in the general section, set the app source icon to the one with only the iPhone/iPad icons. Then goto the watch kit app, and set the app source icon to the one with only the watch kit icons

6) Go through each folder for each of the 3 targets and go into the info.plist, and remove all of the icon keys. There were 1-3 of these in each info.plist. I just deleted them. The info.plist can be found by tapping on the target, or looking in your folder hierarchy. These are the 3 info.plists you need to look through:
   a) Regular app's plist
   b) watch kit extension's plist
   c) watch kit app's plist

7) Finally, I went into the watch kit app's plist one last time and added a new key: **CFBundleIconFiles**
When I added this new key, Xcode changed the name to Icon Files. 
This is an array which I added one at a time each of the watch icon file's names:
    AppIcon24x24@2x.png
    AppIcon27.5x27.5@2x.png
    AppIcon29x29@2x.png
    AppIcon29x29@3x.png
    AppIcon40x40@2x.png
    AppIcon44x44@2x.png
    AppIcon86x86@2x.png
    AppIcon98x98@2x.png

Finally! Success! Hopefully this helps everyone out who is stuck with this lame problem. P.S. Sorry if there are formatting issues. Stack thinks I am writing code so had to indent, when I wasn't.

Answer (score 0):

it also can be related with the alpha channel (transparency) of your icons. More info: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/watch/

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and wasted me almost whole day to fix the issue. Before I figured out the solution, I tried every advice you guys posted but failed in the end.
Here is my stupid way to fix it: **ALL** the icons in the App Icon should have the same *color profile*, in my case, two of icons are different from others. After I changed the other two color format, it works.

[image: color profile comparison]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error but it ended up that my 27.5x27.5@sx.png image was 56x56 but apple needed it to be 55x55