# Apple Watch icon issue upon submission

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch

I'm trying to submit an iOS app to the App Store (one that supports the new Apple Watch) and I'm having major issues with the required icon files, their names and sizes. I've read the documentation (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/WatchHumanInterfaceGuidelines/IconandImageSizes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014992-CH16-SW1) and it says to create icons @2x of sizes 48, 55, 80, 88, 172, and 196. What does this mean, Icon-48x48@2x.png (96px x 96px) or Icon-24x24@2x.png (48px x 48px).

When I submit my binary it keeps giving me errors... ERROR ITMS 90394 Missing Icon ... ERROR ITMS 90392 Invalid Icon

Could some please explain Exactly what icon names and sizes I need to include please?!?

I've guessed and checked for hours ... Icon-48x48@2x.png (88px x 88px) is no good ... Icon-24x24@2x.png (44px x 44px) is no good!

Also, do I add the icon files to the WatchKit App Extension or just the WatchKit App?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29335509/watchkit-appicon-the-app-icon-set-named-appicon-did-not-have-any-applicable/29337514#29337514

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]
Go to your story board, open your WatchKit App folder, click on the Image.xcassets in there you should see the AppIcon asset, click on it and it will show you all the icon sizes. If you click on each one, the attribute inspector will give you the pixel dimensions for each.

Answer (score 3):

I was also struggling with the same problem. It's really annoying one. Searched for it and did all things mentioned above and in sone other posts over Internet. Though nothing worked.

Well then i realised 24x24@2x should be actually of size 48x48 pixels not  24x24 and so on. I know it's a dumb one. But i guess there are more dumb people like me and this post will help them.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely import the icons into WatchKit App.
There should be one predefined image asset named "AppIcon" where you should add your icons. It worked great for me, I just updated my app to App Store review.

Btw, you should import all images that you use in AppleWatch app into the WatchKit App instead of Extension, otherwise you the images are sent from iPhone into AppleWatch when the Extension communicates with the WatchKit App...

Answer (score 1):

After many many attempts I finally was able to successfully submit my watch supported app to the store.

I'm unsure exactly which part was causing the issue, but one thing I did was use the naming convention outlined (by mrdoktor) in this thread: [Invalid Apple Watch icon file names must match pattern "*<dimension>@<scale>x.png"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29423475/invalid-apple-watch-icon-file-names-must-match-pattern-dimensionscalex-pn)

Note: I only named the watch app icons in this manner ... the regular icons (for iPhone/iPad) are named like **icon72@2x.png** etc.

I then went into Xcode's organizer->projects and deleted the "derived data" for the project.

Also, in my WatchKit App I have an images.xcassets file and to it I created a "New App Icon" set which I named "AppIcon-Watch". I went into my project's settings and under the WatchKit App target I made sure that the App Icons Source was pointing to the newly created "AppIcon-Watch" set.

I did not have to touch the WatchKit Extension and it's images.xcassets. I did not have to add the icons to the extension either.

I did have to add the watch icon files to the WatchKit App folder and import them into the project, and further drag them into the correct place within the WatchKit's images.xcassets

I hope this helps everyone else that is having this same issue!

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the 90392 error, not from my app icons but from three other miscellaneous images I included in my watch app. I had added them directly as files in my project, which is the old school way before image assets. I deleted these and added them to an image asset catalog instead and then the app submission went through. The files and filenames were the same, so apparently all images must be part of an asset catalog.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and successfully fixed it. The most strange thing is that icon named in manner `40x40@2x.png` should be only home screen `38mm`. As soon as I named it in this manner my App was successfully uploaded to **AppStore**. But ALL MY OTHER ICONS for `AppWatch` are named as usually: icon_180.png
Magic which is not understandable for me. :-)