# Apple Watch Extension does not show up when archive

Tags: ios, apple-watch

I tried different methods, included the one shows in this post: [Apple Watch icon issue upon submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29808379/apple-watch-icon-issue-upon-submission)

The icon did show up in My Watch setting, but not in the archive process for submission

[Submission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nuAi2.png)

Also tried to change the AppIcon to a different name and link it in Xcode, it did not help. The app could be submitted those, there is no warning about the icon, it just did not show up.

Comment: Make sure that you have uploaded App Icons for both watch and phone.

Comment: Already done in iTunesconnect, any other hints?

Comment: @KenLee have you solved this problem? I've been stucked same issue.